# TCPDF how to prevent page break within a block (split content)?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I'm making a PDF with TCPDF and can't figure out how to make a block consistent that it doesn't break between pages...

Here is my `<div>` representing a code block:

[image: content broken layout TCPDF]

How can I make it to be on second page please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div nobr="true">content</div>
```

[Documentation](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_048/)

Comment: Zver25, perhaps your answer could be improved by explaining why the OP couldn't get this to work, or why your answer works. Just some friendly advice.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define a new page before your block of code to make it go to the next page so that it is not split.

such code would look like this

```
 $pdf->AddPage();
```

this assumes you are using the variable $pdf to define your document (ie $pdf = new MYPDF() )

Comment: Hi ! thx for answer but I'm looking for a dynamic way to do it, something like -> if the block is splitted then `$pdf->AddPage();`

Comment: Oh okay, have you tried $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 0);